# Creating a table into a data base on hue from kafka streming data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, hue, flink-sql

I want to ceate a table in hue plateform from reading kafka topic but i always get an empty table as shown in the picture :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wjfR.png)

this is my  example of code using flink sql client version 1.14.5:

```
SET 'pipeline.name' = 'aSQL';

-- Define available catalogs
CREATE CATALOG Abb WITH (
    'type' = 'hive',
    'default-database' = abc',
    'hive-conf-dir' = '/etc/hive/conf'    
);


USE CATALOG Abb;

USE abc;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a_kaf (
  START_DATE         STRING,
  END_DAT         STRING, …….

) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'name of topic',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'xxxxxxx just exp xxxxxxx: 9092',
    'properties.group.id' = 'xxxxxx',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
    'format' = 'csv',
    'csv.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
    'csv.field-delimiter' = '\t'
);
```

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in creating this real-time table for streaming data on HUE.

Comment: Did you try to change `latest-offset` to something else so you can get existing data?

Comment: Yes, actually I tried all the options : 'earliest-offset', 'latest-offset', 'group-offsets', 'timestamp' and 'specific-offsets' and still the same result, I only can read the topic when i use temporary mode to create the table and then select but of course I can't get the table on HUE.

Comment: I've never used Kafka with Hue, but I remember finding that it had its own plugin for Kafka, separate from any notebook or SQL functionality. Regardless, if you can work with FlinkSQL from your terminal, any notebook should work the same

Comment: I'm not sure what is your expectation, but I also don't know Hue. You're only creating a Kafka topic definition, but you aren't querying any data. I'm not sure if clicking on the table in Hue equals something like 'SELECT * from a_kaf`, because else it won't show data. I would also recommend to check the Flink logs on your cluster for any potential issues